# Calculation based on user input

Tags: python

```
a = int(input("Enter the first number: "))
b = int(input("Enter the second number: "))


calc = ('Please enter your calculation, + to add, - to subtract, * to multiply and / to divide:')

if calc == ('+'):
    def add(a,b):
        add = a + b
        return add
print("The Sum is: ", str(a)+str(b))


if calc == ('-'):
    def sub(a, b):
        diff = a - b
        return diff
print("The Difference is: ", str(a)+str(b))

if calc == ('*'):
    def mul(a, b):
        multi = a*b
        return multi
print("The product is: ", str(a)+str(b))

if calc == ('/'):
    def div(a, b):
        divi = a/b
        return divi
print("The division is: ", str(a)+str(b))
```

So, if I enter 2 for a and 4 for b, then print say add, it should only show 6, but it sticks together as 24 and all of them shows, so the addition subtraction, etc., all of them as 24, pls help me.  EDIT: It does not ask me if I want to add, subtract, multiply or divide

Comment: Why do you define functions and then don't use them? How does the expression following "The division is:" make sense to you? Why do you print unconditionally four outputs?

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be calling the function inside each block, just defining it. There also seems to be some indentation errors in the code and it's missing the input keyword for setting the value of calc. Try the below code and see if it works.

```
a = int(input("Enter the first number: "))
b = int(input("Enter the second number: "))


calc = input('Please enter your calculation, + to add, - to subtract, * to multiply and / to divide:')

if calc == ('+'):
    def add(a,b):
        add = a + b
        return add
    print("The Sum is: ", add(a, b))


if calc == ('-'):
    def sub(a, b):
        diff = a - b
        return diff
    print("The Difference is: ", sub(a, b))

if calc == ('*'):
    def mul(a, b):
        multi = a*b
        return multi
    print("The product is: ", mul(a, b))

if calc == ('/'):
    def div(a, b):
        divi = a/b
        return divi
    print("The division is: ", div(a, b))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should simplify your operations, keep only the operations with a and b and take off the functions :

```
a = int(input("Enter the first number: ")) 
b = int(input("Enter the second number: "))
calc = input('Please enter your calculation, + to add, - to subtract, * to multiply and / to divide: ')

if calc == ('+'): 
    add = a + b 
    print("The Sum is:", add)

if calc == ('-'): 
    diff = a - b 
    print("The Difference is: ", diff)

if calc == ('*'): 
    multi = a * b 
    print("The product is: ", multi)

if calc == ('/'): 
    divi = a / b 
    print("The division is: ", divi)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you do not print the result of any function, you print the concatenation of the two numbers and you should call the function inside the if statement, not declare it.

First, you should define the functions outside the if statements.

```
  def add(a,b):
    return a+b
    
  def multiply(a,b):
     return a*b

  def substract(a,b):
     return a-b

  def divide(a,b):
      "Note here that b should be different from 0"
       return a/b
    
  a = int(input("Enter the first number: "))
  b = int(input("Enter the second number: "))
    
  calc = input('Please enter your calculation, + to add, - to subtract, * to multiply and / to divide:')
    
  if calc == ('+'):   print("The Sum is: ", add(a,b))
  if calc == ('-'):   print("The Difference is: ", substract(a,b))
  if calc == ('*'):   print("The multiplication is: ", multiply(a,b))
  if calc == ('/'):   print("The division is: ", divide(a,b))
```

I hope this one helps you!

Comment: It's missing an input statement where the value of calc is being set.

Comment: True. I missed this little aspect. Thank you. edited.

Answer (score 0):

you have to put input before to enter to ask

- calc = input('Please enter your calculation, + to add, - to subtract, * to multiply and / to divide:')
- add '*' in if condition for product condition
- remove the str function from the print condition in every if condition